# Overlay scroll bar doesn't work in mozilla and IE

Tags: html, css

In our application we have a table with dynamic no of rows and columns.. same directive is used for displaying two different tables. I have added a overlay scroll bar to table...  that's working fine in chrome but in Mozilla and IE it doesn't.. In both browsers it acts like normal scrollbar and causes misalignment.. Can someone help me with this.. any other solution to avoid table misalignment.
https://jsfiddle.net/KrishnaAnanthi/t1vna5uz/

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
}

.filter-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
}

.header-container {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-text {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.header-text {
  color: #000000;
  font-weight: normal;
  word-break: break-all;
}

tbody.scrollContent {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: overlay;
  background-color: white;
}

tbody {
  display: block;
}

.header-text {
  width: 90%;
  float: left;
  text-align: start;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.icon-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -10px;
}

.sort-icon {
  float: right !important;
  clear: right;
  height: 1px !important;
}

thead,
tbody tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:80%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class='filter-container header-container'>
          <div class='header-text'> Name of station </div>
          <div class='icon-right'> <span class="fa fa-sort-asc fa-lg sort-icon "></span><span class="fa fa-sort-desc fa-lg sort-icon  "></span></div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class='filter-container header-container'>
          <div class='header-text'> lastname</div>
          <div class='icon-right'> <span class="fa fa-sort-asc fa-lg sort-icon "></span><span class="fa fa-sort-desc fa-lg sort-icon  "></span></div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class='filter-container header-container'>
          <div class='header-text'> Age</div>
          <div class='icon-right'> <span class="fa fa-sort-asc fa-lg sort-icon "></span><span class="fa fa-sort-desc fa-lg sort-icon  "></span></div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class='filter-container header-container'>
          <div class='header-text'> Address</div>
          <div class='icon-right'> <span class="fa fa-sort-asc fa-lg sort-icon "></span><span class="fa fa-sort-desc fa-lg sort-icon  "></span></div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class='filter-container header-container'>
          <div class='header-text'> Hobby</div>
          <div class='icon-right'> <span class="fa fa-sort-asc fa-lg sort-icon "></span><span class="fa fa-sort-desc fa-lg sort-icon  "></span></div>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class='scrollContent'>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>Bangalore</td>
      <td>Playing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>Bangalore</td>
      <td>Playing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>Bangalore</td>
      <td>Playing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>Bangalore</td>
      <td>Playing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>Bangalore</td>
      <td>Playing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>Bangalore</td>
      <td>Playing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>Bangalore</td>
      <td>Playing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>Bangalore</td>
      <td>Playing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>Bangalore</td>
      <td>Playing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>Bangalore</td>
      <td>Playing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>Bangalore</td>
      <td>Playing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>Bangalore</td>
      <td>Playing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>Bangalore</td>
      <td>Playing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>Bangalore</td>
      <td>Playing</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: misalignment becoz of scrollbar]

Answer (score 0):

Actually when we set width of table dynamically and set overflow to scroll we can get expected result. And the width has to be set for all column except the last column.
lets say we have table with 5 column we need to set width for first four column and fifth column will auto adjust

```
#table_id thead tr th:nth-child(2),
#table_id thead tr th:nth-child(3),
#table_id thead tr th:nth-child(4),
#table_id tbody tr td:nth-child(2),
#table_id tbody tr td:nth-child(3),
#table_id tbody tr td:nth-child(4) {
    width: calc((100vw - 150px) / 4);
}
```